# Converting Google Sites to normal website

Tags: html, google-sites, converters

I've designed a nice looking Google Sites website on Google Sites, however, after the completion, we've noticed that you can't monetize Google Sites.

Is there a way to monetize them, and if not, is there a tool to convert a Google Site to a normal HTML/CSS website? Where would you start if you'd like to replicate it step by step, if such tool does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

If by *monitize*, you mean display adverts like AdSense, then that is the situation at the momement; they are not allowed and I doubt they will be any time soon.

Google Takeout (takeout.google.com) is the standard way to extract things from Google. Checkout this [link](https://www.steegle.com/google-sites/how-to/export-with-takeout)